Choosing the next available device for parallel testing with Appium and UIAutomator2
i am currently trying to enhance our Testautomatisation infrastructure by parallelizing our tests. I know how to do that but I am running into the question of device management. Imagine I have 5 different devices and 10 Test I want to run in parallel. Every Test takes a different amount of time and may run again on failure. I could now choose for every test one specific device but I don't want to do that. Instead I want to have a piece of code that decides for me which device is free and uses that one. I can do that by looking up the current Sessions on my Appium Server. That works fine until two test are starting at the same time. Then UiAutomator2 is selecting the same device for both tests and on is failing with the Expection
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. 
My Question now is has anyone here experience with parallelizing Tests on multiple devices and can suggest some things I can try? I am using Appium as a Server Android as an OS Java as a Programming Language and TestNG.
Here is the code of my suit
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM
        "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="FirstSuit" configfailurepolicy="continue" verbose="10" parallel="tests">


    <test name="FirstTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="org.example.FirstAppiumTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="SecondTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="org.example.SecondAppiumTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>


</suite>

Here is my code how I currently check for busyDevices
private URL getHubUrl() {
    URL remoteAddress = null;
    try {
        remoteAddress = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Assert.fail("Selenium Grid address is malformed. Exception message: ", e);
    }
    return remoteAddress;
}

public void setDriver() {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

    caps.setCapability("platformName", "android");
    caps.setCapability("appium:automationName", "uiautomator2");
    
    caps.setCapability("appium:appPackage", "com.example.exampleApp");
    caps.setCapability("appium:appActivity",   "com.example.exampleApp.frontend.MainActivity");
    
    List<String> busyDevices = get_busyDevices("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    
    List<String> availableDevices = findIdleDevices(Constants.allDevices, busyDevices);
    
    if (!availableDevices.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("SecondTest running on " + availableDevices.getFirst());
        caps.setCapability("appium:udid", availableDevices.getFirst());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("No device found");
    }
    
    driver = new AndroidDriver(getHubUrl(), caps);
}

public List<String> findIdleDevices(List<String> allDevices, List<String> busyDevices) {
     return allDevices.stream()
             .filter(device -> !busyDevices.contains(device))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static List\<String\> get_busyDevices(String appiumServerUrl) {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(appiumServerUrl + "/sessions");
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
            return  extract_Udid(jsonResponse);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public static List<String> extract_Udid(JSONObject jsonResponse) {
    JSONArray valueArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("value");
    List<String> udidList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject capabilities = valueArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("capabilities");
        String udid = capabilities.getString("udid");
        if (!udidList.contains(udid)) {
            udidList.add(udid);
        }
    }
    return udidList;
}

